# Why would ping oscillate between receiving bytes and redirects over a VPN?

Tags: vpn, ping, openswan

I have a VPN set up between an Ubuntu 14 VM under fusion on my side and a SonicWall on the other side. The Ubuntu VM is dedicated to the task.

When I ping a remote address, the results are very strange. Sometimes I get back the expected 64 bytes. Other times I get a redirect. Other times I get a host unreachable. These are all intermingled.

```
PING 192.168.110.11 (192.168.110.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 172.24.100.45: icmp_seq=1 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.110.11)
64 bytes from 192.168.110.11: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=46.7 ms
From 172.24.100.15 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.24.100.15 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.24.100.15 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.24.100.45: icmp_seq=6 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.110.11)
64 bytes from 192.168.110.11: icmp_seq=6 ttl=63 time=47.7 ms
From 172.24.254.1: icmp_seq=7 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 172.24.100.45)
From 172.24.100.45: icmp_seq=7 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.110.11)
64 bytes from 192.168.110.11: icmp_seq=7 ttl=63 time=51.7 ms
From 172.24.100.15 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
```

192.68.110.11 is the remote host that I am attempting to ping.
172.24.100.45 is the Ubuntu host running my side of the VPN.
172.24.100.15 is a local Ubuntu host from which I am issuing the ping.

Suggestions?

Comment: There is not enough information here for anyone to speculate.  You would have to provide your routes and their weights, vpn config, network config / topology.  When you say remote address, is your vpn the only possible path?  Is the IP just on the other end of that VPN or are there other routers / devices?